# Spark MapGroupsWithState Update function doesn't allow action queries like filter, count, show etc

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have an IoT application where I receive the data from different Energy Meters and Inverter Meters. These meters continuously sends meter value as no of units consumed. This value continuously increments over period of time and I have to calculate One hour Energy Consumption for each meter.

I get all this data in a kafka topic from which I create Structured Streaming Dataframe.

On this expanded dataframe I am applying mapGroupsWithState function. This should return me one hour generation.

The Problem:
I am not able to do any of the count, show, filter, aggregation operations inside update function using spark dataframe.

```
    val df_output = final_df
      .selectExpr("*")
      .as[input_row_druid]
      .groupByKey(_.plant_slug)
      .mapGroupsWithState(GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout)(updateAcrossEvents)
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .outputMode("update")
      .start()

    df_output.awaitTermination()


  def updateAcrossEvents(plant_slug:String, inputs: Iterator[input_row_druid],
                         oldState: GroupState[source_state]):out_state = {
    val spark_session = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    import spark_session.implicits._

    val list_of_list = inputs.toList
    val new_df = list_of_list.toDF
    var my_state:source_state = if (oldState.exists) oldState.get else source_state(plant_slug,list_of_list)

    println("Printing inverter and merter df with counts")
    val inverter_df = new_df.filter($"device_type" === "INVERTER")
    val meter_df = new_df.filter($"device_type" === "METER")
    println(inverter_df.show())
    val inv_count = inverter_df.count()
    println(meter_df.show())
    val meter_count = meter_df.count()
    println(inv_count)
    println(meter_count)

    val new_state = source_state(plant_slug, list_of_list)
    oldState.update(new_state)
    var out = out_state(plant_slug,inv_count.toString,meter_count.toString)
    out
  }
```

If I do not do any filter operation new_df.show prints all data in dataframe. But count, show, filter not functioning.

One thing I noticed that is whenever I submit job to spark it runs in multiple batches, batch 0 is always successful but it hangs on batch 0. It never proceeds in next batch.

This is expected Result

```
+--------------------+-------+---------+
|          plant_slug|inv_gen|meter_gen|
+--------------------+-------+---------+
|              plant1|     11|       10|
|              plant2|     20|       19|
|              plant3|     40|       38|
|              plant4|     59|       57|
|              plant5|     37|       35|
+--------------------+-------+---------+
```